# matching a substring in a dateframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to match the ID column in my dataframe if the name contain a string say 'test_'. Is there a simple way to get the Boolean vector like df.ID == 'something' for df.ID contains 'test_'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC then the following should work:

```
df.loc[df['ID'].str.contains('test_'), 'ID']
```

this will return all ID's that contain the partial string

If you want a boolean array against all rows:

```
df['ID'].str.contains('test_')
```